# How to add translations (i18n) to an NPM package using rollup.js?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, rollupjs, react-i18next

I am trying to add translations to an NPM package that I am building using [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/).

Since I am currently using the library `react-i18next` in other react apps, I decided to try to use it in my rollup project which is also using react. However, I keep getting the following error:

`react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next`

This is what I have tried so far:

```
// index.tsx
import './i18n';
```

```
// i18n.ts
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import * as i18n from 'i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

import en from './locales/en.json';

// t function can return null, this behaviour is set by default,
// if you want to change it, set returnNull type to false.
// as per docs
declare module 'i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    returnNull: false;
  }
}

i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    debug: false,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    nsSeparator: ':',
    resources: {
      en: en,
    },
    keySeparator: false,
    returnNull: false,
  });

export { i18n };
```

The code above works in other react projects. I am guessing that I need to add `i18next` as a plugin somehow to `rollup.config.js` but I was not able to find anything on the internet on how to do it.

How can I get this to work? I am also happy to switch i18n libraries if it needs be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've headed the same problem and couldn't find an answer int he internet, so I solved it using the provider that i18n yields to instantiate the i18n element, and then wrapping the main export in this provider to be standalone. Here are the examples of how my files ended.

##### i18n.ts

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

import enTranslation from '{path-to-translations}/en/common.json';
import esTranslation from '{path-to-translations}/es/common.json';

i18n
  /*
   * i18next-browser-language detector allow i18n to get the browser language as default option language.
   */
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  /*
   * initReactI18next allows to integrate i18n with React components.
   */
  .use(initReactI18next)
  /*
   * Here i18n it's initialized
   */
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    resources: {
      en: { common: enTranslation },
      es: { common: esTranslation },
    },
    ns: 'common',
    // debug: true,
    keySeparator: '.',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });
export const nameSpace = {
  common: 'common',
};
export default i18n;
```

##### TranslationWrapper.tsx

```
/* other imports */
import { I18nextProvider, useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from '../modules/i18n';

const TranslationWrapper = (props) => {
    return <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      {props.children}
    </I18nextProvider>
};

export default TranslationWrapper;
```

Then wrap every component in this translationWrapper and you should have the `useTranslation` hook available to use like `const { t } = useTranslation('common')` in every component.

Last of all be sure to dedupe the `useTranslation`, `i18n` and `I18nextProvider` in the `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` plugin configuration to not having them declared one time per component and having only one for all components, something like

##### rollup.config.js

```js
export default {
  ...,
 plugins: [
      ...,
      resolve({
        ...{rest-config}
        dedupe: ['useTranslation', 'i18n', 'I18nextProvider', ...],
      }),
      ...
    ],
  ...
}
```

This worked for me because it's a pretty simple library without lots of components, but if you'd like to avoid having every component wrapped in the provider because I know it's not nice to be re-exporting every component but this time wrapped in a provider, you can look into the [withTranslation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc) HOC that works similar to the provider but in a more friendly to the components syntax.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: once you use this component in a react project, how did you manage to mock i18next from the web component? I have not worked out how to do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am also using i18next on the parent app (where these web components are used), I had to create my own instance of i18n to make sure they were treated separately:

```js
import i18next from 'i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import en from './locales/en.json';

// t function can return null, this behaviour is set by default,
// if you want to change it, set returnNull type to false.
// as per docs
declare module 'i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    returnNull: false;
  }
}

const i18n = i18next.createInstance();

i18n.use(LanguageDetector).init({
  debug: false,
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  nsSeparator: ':',
  resources: {
    en: en,
  },
  keySeparator: false,
  returnNull: false,
});

export { i18n };
```